# how can I get related users, of a given team? DRF

Tags: python, django

How can I get the users that are to a team, Ex: where Team master = 1 for example

this is my models :

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

# Create your models here.
class Team(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)

class TeamUser(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializer :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.teams.models import Team, TeamUser

class TeamUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamUser
        fields = '__all__'


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to get all the users that are related to team master 1

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(teamuser__team__master_id=1)
```

This will retrieve all `CustomUser`s that have a related `TeamUser` that relates to a `Team` with as `master` a `CustomUser` with as primary key `1`.

Comment: how can i do it in   DRF ?

Comment: @AliceMunin: if you work with a `ModelViewSet`, you can specify the `queryset=` attribute: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: should i change any thing in my serializer

Comment: @AliceMunin: normally not, since the serializer is only concerned to transform model objects into a stream of data (JSON, XML, etc.).

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and prefetch_related  :)

Comment: @AliceMunin: but this is about filtering. `prefetch_related` should be used if you are loading a lot of items from another model. Here we do not load the related `Team`s, etc. in memory, we still only have the custom user. You can however combine filtering and `.prefetch_related(..)`, for example filter, and prefetch the items for that prefetch object.

Comment: what is the best way in your point of view in my situation :)